# MicroController execute code from external SRAM

Tags: arm, microcontroller

I've done some researches on ARM. Executing instructions that been loaded into external SRAM is slow.

I'm wondering if there are any microcontrollers that execute code from external SRAM as fast as from internal SRAM?

And I'm expecting to put a 1G external SRAM. Does microcontroller support that many memory?

Thanks.

Comment: **1 GB** of SRAM?! Oh to have pockets that deep...

Comment: Internal versus External is not really meaningful.  A modern ARM typically has multiple buses.  APB, AHB, and AXI; See: [AMBA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Microcontroller_Bus_Architecture).  Each bus will have different speeds/bandwidth.  For instance, one bus maybe 16bit and another 128bit.  The bus bandwidth versus the CPU frequency determine whether something is **fast** or **slow**.  A DDR5 controller on an ACE bus maybe faster than some ARM CPUs.  In other words, you need the right system, not necessarily 1G of SRAM.

Answer (score 1):

[SRAM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Static_random-access_memory) [[1]](http://www.eeherald.com/section/design-guide/esmod15.html), Static RAM is an expensive technology compared to [DRAM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DRAM), Dynamic random-access memory so most of the time you get a small amount of SRAM and relatively much bigger DRAM in computing devices. SRAM is generally used as small separated storage directly coupled to CPUs or to implement caches. In case of MCUs manufacturers tries to give you [different approaches](http://www.digikey.com/en-US/articles/techzone/2012/jan/memory-considerations-for-faster-mcus) to utilize such layered hardware.